General relativity problem from Wald's book
I'm self-studying General Relativity using Carroll's and Wald's book, and I'm confused about this problem from Wald (Chapter 3, Problem 2).
Suppose that $M$ is a manifold with metric $g_{ab}$ and associated derivative operator $\nabla_a$. A solution of the equation $\
nabla_a \nabla^a \alpha = 0$ is called a harmonic function. IN the case where $M$ is a two-dimensional manifold, let $\alpha$ be harmonic and let $\epsilon_{ab}$ be an antisymmetric tensor field satisfying $\epsilon_{ab} \epsilon^{ab} = 2(-1)^s$, where $s$ is the number of minuses in the signature of the metric. Consider the equation $\nabla_a \beta = \epsilon_{ab} \nabla^b \alpha.$

Show that the integrability conditions for this equation are satisfied (by this, I think they mean to show that $d \alpha = 0$, so that there exists some $\beta$ so that $d \beta = \alpha$), and thus, locally, there exists a solution, $\beta.$ Show that $\beta$ also is harmonic, in that $\nabla_a \nabla^a \beta = 0.$
By choosing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as coordinates, show that the metric takes the form $$ds^2 = \pm \Omega^2(\alpha, \beta) [d \alpha^2 + (-1)^2 d \beta^2].$$

I'm still working on the first part. Firstly I have a clarification question: I don't think the notation $\nabla^a$ (with the index on the superscript) has been defined; I am figuring that $\nabla_a$ and $\nabla^a$ both refer to the same derivative operator, and this notation just allows us to sum (since formally you need to sum lower indices with upper indices).
To show that $d \alpha = 0$, I am just trying to manipulate the formula $$d \alpha = (p+1) \nabla_{[ b} \alpha_{a_1, \dots, a_p]},$$ but it's unclear to me how to use the Harmonic condition from here. Maybe this is the wrong approach. Does anyone have any hints?

that upper (superscript) index is obtained from the lower index using the (inverse) metric $g^{ab}$

The contravariant derivative operator $\nabla^a$ is defined naturally by raising the covariant index of the covariant derivative operator $\nabla_a$ (terminology as in Wald's book): $$ \nabla^a \equiv g^{ab},\nabla_b ,. $$
You're right about why this is needed. $\nabla^a\nabla_a = \nabla_a\nabla^a$ is the good old Laplacian operator from vector calc (now generalized to any manifold).

Got it, that makes sense. I'm now trying to show that $\beta$ is harmonic. My strategy, roughly speaking, was to raise the index on the LHS of the equation $\nabla_a \beta = \epsilon_{ab} \nabla^b \alpha$ using the metric to get something like $$ \nabla^d \beta = g^{da} \epsilon_{ab} \nabla^b \alpha,$$ and then apply $\nabla_d$ to both sides of the equation. However, I'm not quite sure how to show that the RHS is 0. Is this the right strategy?
